# How to prevent an application to run in Launcher?

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

I have created a launcher application **"MyOwnLauncher"** and another andoid application **"MyOwnProject"**.
User has option to select default android launcher or my custom launcher "MyOwnLauncher".

I want to prevent the user to run "MyOwnProject" application, if the user selects the default launcher.
I only want to allow user to run "MyOwnProject" application, if it is from my custom launcher "MyOwnLauncher".

I successfully created my custom launcher application "MyOwnLauncher" and displayed my "MyOwnProject" application icon in my custom laucher home activity. The application runs if the user clicks on the icon. [I am following the doc. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html]

How can I prevent the user to run "MyOwnProject" application if it not from my custom launcher application "MyOwnLauncher"?

Thanks in advance.
Romah

Comment: Your app is showin the launcher because of the intent filters you supply in your manifest, you would have to implement your own custom intent filter in your launcher and remove the standard android one's

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand, but you can make it so your app does not show in any app launchers by removing

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

from the `<intent-filter>` section in all activities in your `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: My manifest file:`<activity android:name=".Home" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" /> --> </intent-filter> </activity>`

Comment: actually, remove category LAUNCHER from all activities!

Comment: @AlexCohn that is true. Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent the user to run "MyOwnProject" application if it not from my custom launcher application "MyOwnLauncher"?

You can't but more important, you shall not do that! Stuff like that is treated like [*bloatware*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloatware).